# How to code for flashPlayer 10.2 inside of flash

Tags: flash

I am wanting to try some of the new features of Flash Player 10.2 in flash.When I go to import some of the new classes they do not work.

How can I set Flash up to use the new features of the current SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, if you [compile using the Flex SDK](http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/10/26/using-the-flex-sdk-with-flash-cs4/) from the Flash IDE. You just need to make sure to get an SDK that compiles toward 10.2; probably the [Hero](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/flexsdk/Download+Flex+Hero) builds.

However, the Flash IDE is notoriously bad for coding. I'd recommend always using something external.